# Access form property inside a nested formGroup

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

How to access a form property inside a nested formGroup? That might sound confuse but I think the code will help you guys understand.
This is the formGroup, and as you can see there's an array inside the formGroup:

```
      this.formDadosBancarios = this._fb.group({
        id: [''],
        dados_titular: this._fb.array([
          this.initTitular()
        ])
      })

   initTitular(){
        return this._fb.group({
            titular: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(3)]],
            cnpj: [''],
            cpf: ['', Validators.required],
            data_nasc: ['', Validators.required],
            agencia: ['', <any>Validators.required ],
            banco: ['', <any>Validators.required],
            conta: ['', <any>Validators.required],
            tipo:  ['', <any>Validators.required],
            pessoa_juridica: ['']
        })
    }
```

and here's the snippet code where I try to access the property `cpf` that is inside ìnitTitular` (I know this code bellow looks nonsense but is just to ilustrate the logic):

```
const cpfCtrl: AbstractControl = this.formDadosBancarios.get('dados_titular').get('cpf');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the `at(index: number) : AbstractControl` method of [`FormArray`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArray-class.html)

```
let array = <FormArray> this.formDadosBancarios.get('dados_titular');
let cpf = array.at(0).get("cpf");
```

I think you can also do this (but I'm unsure for FormArray's `[0]`). See the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html#!#get-anchor)

```
this.formDadosBancarios.get('dados_titular[0].cpf'); //maybe it's ".0" instead of "[0]"
this.formDadosBancarios.get(['dados_titular',0,'cpf']);
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting this error: "Property 'at' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'", do I have to declare something above?

Comment: this one here works like a charm `this.formDadosBancarios.get(['dados_titular',0,'cpf']);`.

Comment: I'm more interrested in the previous one `get('dados_titular[0].cpf')` or `get('dados_titular.0.cpf')`...

Comment: Thank you very much man, it really helped me out, The `0` is the position of the array right? I'm wondering if I gonna have some problems if I add more arrays